# Erro ao tentar usar isset em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Não sei o que tem de errado neste código JavaScript:

```
if( (isset(n1)) && (isset(n2)) ){
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1 + n2;   
}
```

Acho que estou a misturar PHP com JS. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não existe `isset()` em javascript, so em php.

Comment: No caso, como faria ?

Comment: Eu não sei o que você quer fazer. Explique melhor de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em JavaScript não existe [`isset()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) Em PHP o `isset()` tem duas funcionalidades:

- saber se uma variável está declarada
- verificar que o seu valor não é `null`

Para verificares se a variável está declarada em JavaScript tens de usar o [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

O `typeof` é um método que diz qual é o *tipo* da variável, aparentemente não exatamente o que queres. Mas se usares `typeof foo != 'undefined';` então aí já vais ter o que queres, e o `typeof` tem a vantagem de não gerar erros caso a variável não esteja declarada.

Assim em vez de

```
if((isset(n1)) && (isset(n2))){

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1 + n2;   
}
```

podes usar:

```
if(typeof n1 != 'undefined'  && typeof n2 != 'undefined'){

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1 + n2;   
}
```

Se queres também verificar a segunda condição que o `isset()` verifica, ous seja se o valor da variável é diferente de `null`, podes fazer uma verificação simples `if(n1 != null){ // fazer algo`.

Answer (score -2):

```
if ((n1 != undefined) && (n2 != undefined)){
    // Resto do código após verificar se ambas as variáveis estão ou não vazias
}
```

Ou prefiro trocar o `undefined` por `null` em algumas situações, tudo vai depender do valor em que é recebido na variável através do debug do Javascript no navegador.

**EDIT**

Caso os valores passares como um texto, ou melhor, como String na função pode-se comparar com aspas duplas ou simples. Exemplo:

```
if ((n1 != '') && (n2 != '')){
    // Resto do código após verificar se ambas as variáveis estão ou não vazias
}
```

Comment: undefined quer dizer que a variavel ta cheia certo? E já agora como se diz em javascript q a variavel está limpa?

Comment: `undefined` quer dizer que a variável não esta definida, ou seja, não foi atribuido valor a ela. Vou editar a resposta conforme a sua pergunta no comentário

Comment: certo indique me quando a variavel está definida tambem.

Comment: Vai estar definida quando houver um valor atribuido a ela, seja 0, 1, quando o tipo for numérico e "Teste" ou outro valor caso ela for uma String. Para verificar quando esta definida utiliza-se o código que lhe passei acima, até onde eu conheço não existe uma palavra reservada como `undefined` para verificar se a mesma está definida. Então para isso você pode utilizar os códigos de exemplo que lhe respondi.

Comment: Esta resposta dá erro caso `n1` não esteja declarada: (http://jsfiddle.net/pbm23zge/). Deves verificar

Comment: Nesse caso fiz a mesma resposta pensando que as variáveis estavam declaradas, mas bom saber seu exemplo abaixo que também desconhecia.